# shell: HTML templating

Tags: html, bash, sed

I have a small project that takes a HTML template file in it like so;

`<p>Hi, I'm some text for this project!</p>`

and I want it to be read by my bash script but Sed is escaping out at the closing tag which is less than optimmal;

At the moment it looks like this ($postContents being the above HTML text);

```
## Replace <!-- TITLE --> in Head > Title and in Headder > H1 with RealName
sed -i "s/{{TITLE}}/$realname/g" $webdir/blog/$basefile
## Replace <!-- DATE --> With webdate
sed -i "s/{{DATE}}/$webdate/g" $webdir/blog/$basefile
## Replace <!-- CONTENTS --> With postContents
sed -i "s/{{CONTENTS}}/"$postContents"/g" $webdir/blog/$basefile
```

Having manually checked, I'm absolutely sure it's catching on the closing tag. What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Show us sample input & expected output, we will give you nice pointers

Comment: Is it a template file ? If yes, which tool is supposed to edit it ?

Comment: OK, sorry, yeah. I should have mentioned this but bashing (sorry) my head on this for a few hours kinda made me short a bit.

The words in the handlebars are targets in a template file that is copied from the template folder ($webdir/template/postTemp) to the blog folder ($webdir/template/slug) and given verious atributes between date, readable name, all that fun stuff.

Comment: I dunno if someone else delted it but I got it working by swaping the / dilimiator with pipes.

Comment: @CraigMcleod You may be referring to what I wrote, which was to the effect that a different delimiter could be used. It was essentially an extended comment rather than an answer (I described it as being of possible use as a starting point) because of the clearly expressed limitation that if whatever delimiter you choose is present in the replacement string then you are back to exactly the same problem again, but despite this explicit caveat it attracted downvoting, so I withdrew it.  Do you need to see it again?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) (which you should read for other possible solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Better use a *real* template engine.

I think of perl `Template::Toolkit` module or python Jinja.

Using the `tpage` utility, installed with the perl module `Template::Toolkit` (package `libtemplate-perl` on Debian):

```
cat template.tpl
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
</style>
<title>[% title %]</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="[% href %]" title="[% htitle %]" ></a>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```

## The code

```
$ tpage --define title=bar --define href=https://x.j/qs --define htitle=bar template.tpl
```

## Output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
</style>
<title>bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://x.j/qs" title="bar" ></a>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```